# Nginx gives 'Access denied.' when trying to reach any subdirectory

Tags: php, nginx

Any files in the top-level html folder are served properly, but files in any subdirectory such as html/cats/index.php displays only "Access denied." Where to begin figuring out a solution?

My server block looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /home/user/website/html;
    server_name myurl.com www.myurl.com;

    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params;

    }
}
```

access.log shows:

```
73.135.176.74 - - [24/Mar/2021:17:06:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 310 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36"
73.135.176.74 - - [24/Mar/2021:17:06:55 +0000] "GET /cats HTTP/1.1" 403 46 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36"
```

error.log shows:

```
2021/03/24 17:06:55 [error] 88398#88398: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Access to the script '/home/user/website/html/cats' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 73.135.176.74, server: website.com, request: "GET /cats HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "website.com"
```

Comment: Is there any entries in the access log or error log?

Comment: I updated my post to include the most recent logs. /cats 403s. Error.log mentions "see security.limit_extensions" ...hmmm

Comment: Not sure why `/cats` is generating a 403 instead of a 301. But the problem is that you are sending everything to PHP. Is there a reason you are not putting the FastCGI statements into a `location ~ \.php$` block?

Comment: I have layers of problems, but using ~ \.php$ block fixed one of them. Now I'll just go read what that means in the docs. I could stand to learn more about nginx.